# How to get rid of inline code inside a plugin when building a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome Extension using the [midi.js](https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/) plugin.
One of the functions inside that plug returns a script to the DOM, and I don't know how to inject this script directly, which I must do, since it's a security violation.

This is the function -

```
    var addSoundfont = function(text) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.language = "javascript";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.text = text;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
};
```

and this is calling it -

```
    connect.webaudio = function(filetype, instruments, conf) {
    if (MIDI.loader) MIDI.loader.message("Web Audio API...");
    // works awesome! safari, chrome and firefox support.
    var queue = createQueue({
        items: instruments,
        getNext: function(instrumentId) {
            DOMLoader.sendRequest({
                url: MIDI.soundfontUrl + instrumentId + "-" + filetype + ".js",
                onprogress: getPercent,
                onload: function(response) {
                    addSoundfont(response.responseText);
                    if (MIDI.loader) MIDI.loader.update(null, "Downloading...", 100);
                    queue.getNext();
                }
            });
        },
        onComplete: function() {
            MIDI.WebAudio.connect(conf);
        }
    });
};
```

This is the returned script which I copied over into the function, The injected script has created an object that links calls to online sound files (soundfonts). It works, but it's not as elegant as Xan's solution :

```
if (typeof(MIDI.Soundfont) === "undefined") MIDI.Soundfont = {};
MIDI.Soundfont.acoustic_grand_piano = {
    "A0": "data:audio/ogg;base64,T2dn.......
```

Then it goes on forever..

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Where is this script that is being loaded hosted? Inside your extension, on a http URL, on a HTTPS URL? In short, what is an example of a value of `url` in that call?

Comment: It is inside the extension. Used as a plug. The document it throws the script in is the extension body I guess. It throws the inline code error: Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Comment: Last question: where do you run this code? In a background/popup page, or in a content script, or?

Comment: It is only a popup. No background for this one. I'll provide more code if necessary.

Comment: No, it's fine as long as it's not a content script. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of loading the script and then inserting its text inline, you can just inject a `<script src="">` tag with the appropriate URL.

```
getNext: function(instrumentId) {
  // Assuming MIDI.soundfontUrl in in "chrome-extension://" origin
  //  Also, see chrome.runtime.getURL()
  var url = MIDI.soundfontUrl + instrumentId + "-" + filetype + ".js";

  var el = document.createElement("script");
  el.src = url;

  // This is synchronous:
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  queue.getNext();
}
```

This assumes that the js files are packed with the extension. If they are not:

1. The origin MUST be `https://`
2. You need to add the origin to a custom CSP: [Remote Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-remote-script)